# Null Pointer Exception when showing Vungle ads with Admob Mediation

Tags: android, admob, vungle-ads, mobile-ad-mediation

I have integrated Vungle to display a rewarded video ads using Admob as the mediator. On my phone the ads load and play just fine, including when the screen is forced to rotate for the ads orientation. But for a large percentage of users I am seeing this crash below. I am unsure if they are crashing when I first show the ad, or after the ad completes and its coming back to my Activity.

The Admob code was setup per their [documentation](https://admob.googleblog.com/2016/03/mediate-rewarded-video-ads-with-admob.html).
I also followed the Vungle [documentation](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204222794-Get-started-with-Vungle-Android-SDK) as well as making sure to add the required ProGuard [configuration](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463100#proguard).

The crash to me looks like some sort of crash inside of the GoogleApiActivity and my best guess is its related to connecting to google services but given the nature of the code being obfuscated I can't tell whats going wrong.

I am not sure if its possibly related but I am also using the (very new) firebase ads library so maybe thats still really buggy?

At this point I am wondering if its the Admob mediation thats the source of the bugs. I don't expect that Vungle would be relying on a GoogleApiActivity. It could also be a bug with the new Firebase as well. Does anyone have any ideas what the cause of this may actually be?

**Related libraries that are included in the project are:**

- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
- compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0"

**StackTrace**

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5634)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3637)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3043)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3085)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Why is this getting negative votes? Please indicate why? I provided plenty of detail and its well written. Its very inappropriate to just minus vote stuff in this way. Minus votes are for confusing, off topic, or poorly worded questions not difficult questions that you don't care to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vungle Android SDK doesn't support Google-Play_services 9.x yet.
Can you try to use GMS version 8.x instead?

Is that possible for your project?

Thanks,
-aki

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. The app is built on the Firebase SDK which required version 9. When does Vungle expect to have their SDK compatible with the current release?

Comment: I see your situation. Please allow me to get back to you as soon as I find when we plan to support version 9. Sorry for the inconvenience at a moment. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @aki, I also have a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38284517/4843993 Please check it.