# RewardedVideoAd - AdMob Mediation with Vungle - ErrorCode: 3

Tags: android, admob, vungle-ads, mobile-ad-mediation, rewardedvideoad

This is my first time working with video ads. I have followed the AdMob guide of implementing `RewardedVideoAd` from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video?hl=en_US) and the documentation of Vungle from [here](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/207604108). I did all the steps written in these guides. However, when I deploy my app on my mobile, the `RewardedVideoAd` always fails to load. I tested it on my mobile and the emulator, and none of them worked. It always calls onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad. I have the latest Google Play Services installed on both devices. My app is still not deployed on Play Store if that's important to you. I don't know what's wrong. Can someone point out the problem?

ErrorCode is 3: [ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL)

**My Code:**

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    RewardedVideoAd videoAd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        //Some Code

        videoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        videoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
                        reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Bundle extrasBundle = new Bundle();
        extrasBundle.putBoolean("_noRefresh", true);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extrasBundle)
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("D575C31D492903A3BA451D2B2E2BD8E8")
                .build();
        videoAd.loadAd(getString(R.string.video_ad_unit_id), adRequest);

        addLives.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (videoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    videoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AdMob Ad:**

[image: AdMob Ad]

**Ad Mediation:**

[image: Ad Mediation]

**I have added the required libraries for Vungle mediation:**

[image: Vungle Libraries]

**Gradle (project-level):**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

**Gradle (app-level):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'
}
```

**Logcat (regarding ads):**

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved through Vungle Android SDK 4.0.2 and Vungle AdMob Adopter 2.0.0

https://v.vungle.com/sdk
https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/207604108

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just forgot to update this post. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am Aki from Vungle. We are investigating this issue on our end. We will update this thread once we verify it.

Thanks,

Comment: OK, I will be waiting. :)